# Outlook Appointment: Convert EwsId to Appointment UniqueId

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I am using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=15.0.0.0 assembly to create an Appointment instance and calling

```
*Note: ews is a fully defined ExchangeService object*

Appointment appt = new Appointment(ews);
appt.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
return appt.Id.UniqueId;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633661(v%3Dexchg.80)

---

**Problem**

The **UniqueId** returned is **NOT the same** as the EwsId that is attainable through the Outlook javascript API (Office.context.mailbox.item.**itemId**)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5&view=office-js#itemId

---

**Question 1**

Is there a way to convert the Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId (EwsId) into the UniqueId (created as shown above)?

---

**Question 2**

When calling

```
appt.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)
```

Is there a way (I have not found it in Documentation) to not only get the UniqueId from

```
return appt.Id.UniqueId;
```

But also get the corresponding EwsId from the Appointment object? Something like:

```
return appt.EwsId;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the RESTid so you can convert that to a EWSId using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox#converttoewsiditemid-restversion--string

2) appt.Id.UniqueId; should be the EWSId maybe you want to convert that back to the RESTId which you can do with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox#converttorestiditemid-restversion--string